# Service worker requested one time only

Tags: websphere, service-worker, workbox

I'm registering a service worker for my Multiple page web application, It got requested for the first time only, any new page requests or refreshes, it doesn't request the service worker file again, which means no code are running. I couldn't cache my resources.

Environment:
Backend: WCS webspere server.

URL of the service worker: /wcs/service-worker.js

Directory structure: /webContent/service-worker.js

**NOTE: Regarding the URLs all of the URLs are logical one, they didn't match the physical structure. all my pages URLs prefix is /wcs/**

Expectation:
Every time I open the website I got this message in console:

Yay! Workbox is loaded

Current behavior: it just show the message on the first time(i.e while registration)

Code for registration:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/wcs/service-worker.js')
    .then(registration => {
      console.log(`Service Worker registered!`, registration.scope);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(`Service Worker registration failed: ${err}`);
    });
});


}
```

server-worker.js

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
  console.log(`Yay! Workbox is loaded `);
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      /\.js$/,
      new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst()
    );

} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}
```

attached a sample of the HTTP request for the service worker, How the **Referer** Header is the same as the Requested URL, which is the service worker file.

[image: Service worker request]

Comment: Add a bit more logging. Does the call to register the SW succeed or not? application/x-javascript is completely fine. One thing to note: you're placing the SW in /wcs/ directory which reduces the scope of cacheable pages by the SW to everything *under* /wcs/. In other words, that SW _is not able_ to cache anything in /page1/ or /page2/, only stuff in /wcs/page1/, /wcs/page2/ etc. Usually when you only have one SW you should drop it in /sw.js. Google more about "Service Worker scope".

Comment: yes, you are totally right, The registration is successfully completed. Regarding the URLs all of the URLs are logical one, they didn't match the physical structure. all my pages URLs prefix is /wcs/